# Como funciona pivot table no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sou novo em ciência de dados e estou tentando utilizar o [DataFrame.pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) do Pandas para criar um [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) mas ele está me retornando este erro:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Não estou conseguindo resolvê-lo, mas quando altero os parâmetros do `pivot()` funciona, porém, muitos valores retornam como `NaN`.

Pesquisei alguns tópicos sobre isso mas não consegui encontrar uma solução.

O formato do heatmap será com as colunas de ano e as linhas serão os meses.

**Estrutura do DataFrame**

```
data        usuarios    ano     mes      dia    ano-mes     mes-dia
2018-01-01  215         2018    01       01     2018-01     01-01
2018-01-02  167         2018    01       02     2018-01     01-02
2018-01-03  123         2018    01       03     2018-01     01-03
2018-01-04  193         2018    01       04     2018-01     01-04
2018-01-05  235         2018    01       05     2018-01     01-05
2018-01-06  241         2018    01       06     2018-01     01-06
```

**Tipo das Series**

```
data        datetime64[ns]
usuarios             int64
ano                 object
mes                 object
dia                 object
ano-mes             object
mes-dia             object
```

**Tentativas**

```
# Com esse trecho, está me retornando o erro que especifiquei acima
test = df.pivot("ano", "mes", "usuarios")

# Utilizando assim ele até funciona, mas todos os valores ficam NaN
test2 = df.pivot("data", "mes", "usuarios")
```

**Valores após utilizar o pivot `df.pivot("data", "mes", "usuarios")` que funcionou**

```
mes 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12
data                                                
2018-01-01  215.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-02  169.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Por que os valores estão sendo setados como `NaN` e como eu poderia utilizar o `pivot` referenciando apenas o ano e o mês sem retornar o erro mencionado?

Comment: Você poderia adicionar mais linhas ao banco para que a gente possa replicar o erro? Se não puder disponibilizar esses dados, faça um exemplo mínimo replicável. Veja instruções aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Qual a sua unidade de cross-section?

Comment: se possível, procure deixar mais claro qual o output desejado. O seu heatmap vai ter que variáveis na linha e nas colunas?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com as informações que você solicitou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem duas formas de `pivot` no `pandas`, o [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) e a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Tanto o `pivot` quanto a `pivot_table` retornam um `dataframe` como output, a diferença entre elas  é que a primeira não aceita agregação, como pode ser visto na documentação.

## Pivot

Voltando ao seu problema, ao menos para mim, não está claro se existe repetição da combinação `ano-mês` no seu banco. Se não existe repetição, você não precisa de agregação e seu problema pode ser resolvido com `pivot`. Veja um exemplo replicável:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ano': [2017,2018,2017,2018,2017,2018],
                       'mes': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                       'usuarios': [215,167,123,193,235,241]})
print(df)

    ano mes usuarios
0   2017    1   215
1   2018    1   167
2   2017    2   123
3   2018    2   193
4   2017    3   235
5   2018    3   241

df.pivot(values = 'usuarios', index = 'mes', columns = 'ano')
```

Output:

```
ano 2017   2018
mes     
1   215     167
2   123     193
3   235     241
```

## Pivot Table

Por outro lado, se existe repetição no padrão `ano-mês`, então você terá que agregar o número de usuários de alguma forma e terá que usar `pivot_table`. Veja esse exemplo a seguir usando a soma como função de agregação:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ano': [2017,2018,2017,2018,2017,2018],
                       'mes': [1,2,2,2,3,3],
                       'usuarios': [215,167,123,193,235,241]})
df

    ano mes usuarios
0   2017    1   215
1   2018    2   167
2   2017    2   123
3   2018    2   193
4   2017    3   235
5   2018    3   241

df.pivot_table(values = 'usuarios', index = 'mes', columns = 'ano', aggfunc = 'sum')
```

Output:

```
ano 2017    2018
mes     
1   215.0   NaN
2   123.0   360.0
3   235.0   241.0
```

Note que nesse caso, há uma `NaN` no mês 1 de 2018, isso ocorre porque não existe essa entrada no banco original.